# best way to store Google user-ID value in mysql and java

Tags: java, mysql

google user id from token 
e.g.:

```
"sub": "110169484474386276334",
```

[Source](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#verify-the-integrity-of-the-id-token)

Can't seem to find the definition of this number there example is 21 chars long so even a unsigned bigint cant handle it in mysql and a long cant handle it in java,

currently i'm storing it as a string but i feel this may be inefficient, especially as most of my DB work minimum of 50% is going to be lookups on these numbers i want it to be as index friendly as possible, and i have a gut feeling a index on a number will be faster than a index on a string. i have assumed from the limited documentation that there are always numbers.

currently using varchar . thanks

Comment: the expression "google user id" cannot be shortened to "Guid", that doesnt make any sense. In fact, "Guid" is already taken by several, known, **actual** [GUID](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier) manufacturers / developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Keep it as a string.**

Unless you have a very big user base and storage space is a big concern, optimizations like this will most likely cause more trouble that good.

Just one example why storing the id as a number could be a problem:
**Ids with leading zeros**, which will be disregarded if you treat it as a number. `0100` is not necessarily the same id as `100`.